# IRB showing "LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri" error when trying to require "nokogiri"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, irb

In IRB when I type require "nokogiri", I get the following error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri
```

I have the nokogiri gem installed in my gemfile and can use it in Rails with no problem, but in IRB it throws an error.

I'm on OSX Mavericks in case that helps.

Below is a list of my local gems:

> actionmailer (4.0.2)
>   actionpack (4.0.2)
>   activemodel (4.0.2)
>   activerecord (4.0.2)
>   activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
>   activesupport (4.0.2)
>   arel (4.0.1)
>   atomic (1.1.14)
>   builder (3.1.4)
>   bundler (1.3.5)
>   erubis (2.7.0)
>   hike (1.2.3)
>   i18n (0.6.9)
>   mail (2.5.4)
>   mime-types (1.25.1)
>   minitest (4.7.5)
>   multi_json (1.8.2)
>   polyglot (0.3.3)
>   rack (1.5.2)
>   rack-test (0.6.2)
>   rails (4.0.2)
>   railties (4.0.2)
>   rake (10.1.0)
>   sprockets (2.10.1)
>   sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
>   thor (0.18.1)
>   thread_safe (0.1.3)
>   tilt (1.4.1)
>   treetop (1.4.15)
>   tzinfo (0.3.38)

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware that you don't have nokogiri in above list ;) Try running `bundle exec irb` so you will use gems from your Gemfile.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. that worked out for me. if you create an answer then i will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to run `bundle exec irb` to use gems from Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

You should be running 
`require 'rubygems'` 
before loading any other gems. Rails does this for you, but IRB is not that fancy.

Otherwise, are you using a manager like RVM? Did you confirm that you're not switching in or out of a gemset?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that returned false. I guess because it's not in my local gems and only in the rails apps gemfile. I used zrl2dx's suggestion in the comments to use the gems from the gemfile and it worked

Comment: `require 'rubygems'` hasn't been required since Ruby 1.8; and it was widely considered harmful in scripts (but that objection probably doesn't matter much in irb).